# Read csv file c# with comma separator

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to read an csv file with the format:
name, location
Joseph, "street xpto, London"

When I read CSV, I split the file to ",", but when the line has "street xpto, London" (other commas) it doesn't work.

Is there some solution to that? I need to do split ignoring commas when find an " ".

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\example_File.csv"));

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    String[] values = line.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: is the address surrounded by quotations as shown? You would be better looking into a csv parsing library though..

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351864/read-csv-file-when-with-c-sharp-and-dont-read-commas-in-double-quotes)

Comment: `TextFieldParser`or `FileHelpers` are ways to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text field parser handles this already

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("C:\\csv.txt"))
    {
        parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
        while (true)
        {
        string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();
        if (parts == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} field(s)", parts.Length);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are extremely good libraries that will help you do all this. The one I like is `CsvHelper` available through nuget
`Install-Package CsvHelper`
or from the [project home page](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).