# Delimit a string by character unless within quotation marks C#

Tags: c#, csv

I need to demilitarise text by a single character, a comma. But I want to only use that comma as a delimiter if it is not encapsulated by quotation marks.

An example:

```
Method,value1,value2
```

Would contain three values: Method, value1 and value2

But:

```
Method,"value1,value2"
```

Would contain two values: Method and "value1,value2"

I'm not really sure how to go about this as when splitting a string I would use:

```
String.Split(',');
```

But that would demilitarise based on ALL commas. Is this possible without getting overly complicated and having to manually check every character of the string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use an available csv parser like [`VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) or [this](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: [Potential dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829779/splitting-a-csv-and-excluding-commas-within-elements), but highest upvoted/accepted answer is a link only answer... (to one of the articles @Tim just edited in :))

Comment: For completion.. would you mind giving an example of usage for the TextFieldParser for my situation? So I can accept as answer. Thanks for quick responses :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read csv file c# with comma separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678507/read-csv-file-c-sharp-with-comma-separator)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse comma seperated string with a complication in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078054/parse-comma-seperated-string-with-a-complication-in-c-sharp) - *The complication is quotes*

Comment: you can skip character. create method that replace char ',' inside '"' with something else (ex: `\u9999`) then split and finally replace skipped char with ','

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from my comment: Use an available csv parser like [`VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) or [this](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

As requested, here is an example for the `TextFieldParser`:

```
var allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
string sampleText = "Method,\"value1,value2\"";
var reader = new System.IO.StringReader(sampleText);
using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(reader))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; // <--- !!!
    string[] fields;
    while ((fields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        allLineFields.Add(fields);
    }
}
```

This list now contains a single `string[]` with two strings. I have used a `StringReader` because this sample uses a string, if the source is a file use a `StreamReader`(f.e. via [`File.OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Don't suppose you have any insights into why a useful class like this is buried in the VisualBasic namespace?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: you are asking the wrong person. That can only be answered by someone who belonged to the VB.NET/C# compiler team. I guess that such utility classes were important for VB.NET but not for the C# guys. However, since it belongs to the .NET framework you can use it also with C# by adding the reference to the  Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Comment: Yeah fair enough - always just seems odd when I see things like this in there and not "part of" the wider framework.  I can understand things to bring forward VB6 style functions etc, but not stuff like this.  Anyway... offtopic for here.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly the job I was looking for and easy to put in it's own method. :) I also wondered why it is only available in the VisualBasic namespace

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Regex.Split()` to split the data up using the pattern

```
",|(\"[^\"]*\")"
```

This will split by commas and by characters within quotes.

Code Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "Method,\"value1,value2\",Method2";
        string[] pieces = Regex.Split(data, ",|(\"[^\"]*\")").Where(exp => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(exp)).ToArray();

        foreach (string piece in pieces)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(piece);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Method
"value1,value2"
Method2
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lMlhfF)